# create update using Hibernate and Primefaces

Tags: hibernate, jsf

i have a primefaces view with this code,

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" /> 
<p:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
    <h:outputLabel value = "Username" />
    <h:inputText value="#{usersController.users.userId}" id="username"/>
    <h:messages for="username" />

    <h:outputLabel value = "Pertanyaan Rahasia" />
    <p:inputText id="secretQuestion" value="#{usersController.users.secretQuestion}"/>
    <h:messages for="secretQuestion" />

    <h:outputLabel value = "Jawaban Rahasia" />
    <p:inputText id="secretAnswer" value="#{usersController.users.secretAnswer}"/>
    <h:messages for="secretAnswer"/>



    <h:outputLabel value = "Password Lama" />
    <p:password  id="oldPassword" value="#{usersController.users.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Old Password" >
        <f:validator validatorId="com.piwi.controller.usercontroller.passwordController" />
    </p:password>    
    <h:message for="oldPassword" style="color:red" />


    <h:outputLabel value = "Password Baru" for="newPassword"/>
    <p:inputText id="newPassword"  value="#{usersController.users.password}" required="true"/>
    <h:messages for="newPassword" />

    <h:outputLabel value = "Konfirmasi Password" for="confirmPassword"/>
    <p:inputText id="confirmPassword" value="#{usersController.users.password}" required="true" match="newPassword"/>
    <h:messages for="confirmPassword" />


    <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="myButton" action="#{usersController.updateUserPassword}"/><p:commandButton type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

and here my logic :

```
public String updateUserPassword(){
    try{
        LOG.info("Updating Password : "+sessionBean.getUsername());
        String userId = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();           
        userBusinessLogic.doUpdateUser(users);
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOG.error("AdminController.updateUser().", e);
        //e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    //prepareList();
    users = new Users();
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Update Sukses");
    return "create_user.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";

}
public String doUpdateUser(Users users){
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
        trns = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(users);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOG.error("UserBusinessLogic.doUpdateUser()", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(trns != null){
            trns.rollback();
        }
    }finally{
        session.flush();
        session.close();    
    }
    return null;    
}
```

i want to ask, when i'm clicking the update Button, i always got an error where it's say:

```
2014-01-22 19:59:01,396 ERROR - UserBusinessLogic.doUpdateUser()
```

org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or tra
nsient value: com.piwi.dbobject.mlm.Users.fullName

i think my logic is true, and i also don't any other error, when i tried it with another page.

Comment: The identifiant of the entity `Users` is `userId` or `fullName` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, may be you are trying to save a user in DB, without setting `fullName` attribute of it, where you set `fullNamae` not nullable in `Users` class.